# Android TelephonyManager doesn't work with android studio simulator?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am using this simple code to retreive some phone device data, but for some reason any time I open the app on the emulator, it pops up a message saying `"Unfortunately *APP NAME* has closed"` and then it shuts down the app.

this is the code I am using:

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEINumber=tm.getDeviceId();
```

I wrote that code just to test the `Telephonymanager` methods but nothing works except for:
`"getPhoneType();"`

any ideas what's the problem? maybe it is because I am runing it on my android studio emulator?

the problem it says: `getDeviceId: Neither user 10058 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` though I added a permission in the manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

(above the application part)

thank you for your help

Comment: You should maybe look at the error instead of guessing whats wrong.

Comment: @JoxTraex you are more then right. the problem it says: `getDeviceId: Neither user 10058 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` though I added a permission in the manifest

Comment: did you remove your app and reinstall it? also make sure you spelled the permission correctly.

Comment: @JoxTraex - yes... still not working

Comment: @danijinji manifest permission will not work you have ask permissions at run time.Are you compiling against 6.0?

Comment: @SohailZahid can you explain what should I do?

Comment: @danijinji Check my answer below.

Comment: @you have to ask runtime permission.